# Question about proving a theorem (intro to analysis)

Tags: analysis

I am supposed to show that $f^{-1}(G\cup H)=f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$ which is done by showing that $\\f^{-1}(G\cup H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)$ and $f^{-1}(G)\cup f^{-1}(H)\subseteq f^{-1}(G\cup H)$.

The basics of this make sense to me but I'm confused about one part. If I say: Let $x\in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$ do I need to say something along the lines of "then there exists an element $y$ in $(G\cup H)$ such that $y=f(x)$" or am I just fine going straight to "then $f(x)\in (G\cup H)$" without mentioning an element $y$?

Comment: You probably should mention the $y$. For the next step, which is to notice that $y$ must be in either $G$ or $H$ (or both, of course).

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! I recommend you write out the proof with the variable $y$ (and using quantifiers) and then "translate it to aversion that does not use $y$. Then ask a friend of classmate which version (a) is clearer and (b) is more concise. Actually ask if these two proofs prove the same thing.

Comment: There would be nothing wrong with saying, "If $x \in f^{-1}(G\cup H)$, then $f(x)\in G\cup H$." That also covers the case where $G\cup H$ is empty.